# radio button list selectedItem.Value not working when compared to a string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I am using VB.NET and I can't compare the radio button lists selectedItem.Value to a string, it doesn't work...here is the code: (**I have also tried selectedValue it does not work either**)

```
Response.Write("RB1: " + rblOne.SelectedItem.Value + " FML FML FML<br/>")
            If rblOne.SelectedItem.Value = "No" Then
                Response.Write("Hey there!<BR/>")
                pnlR1.Visible = True
                If NumberOfAnswers = 7 Then
                    Score = Score - 10
                ElseIf NumberOfAnswers = 6 Then
                    Score = Score - 15
                Else
                    Score = Score - 20
                End If
                Response.Write("Score: " + Score.ToString)
            End If
    Response.End()
```

If rblOne.SelectedItem.Value = "No" Then is not working, notice the debug statements in there, here is the output:

[image]

Why won't it evaluate that rblOne.SelectedItem.Value = "No" !?!?!? I tried rblOne.SelectedValue, that doesn't work, AND I added .ToString to both, which did not help, I even tried it w/ "No".ToString...this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hi there, that image you've posted seems totally unrelated to the question!

Comment: The image is the output when you run that code

Comment: It displays the fact that the code never falls through the IF statement, because if it did you would see more output to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    If rblOne.SelectedIndex > -1 AndAlso rblOne.Items(rblOne.SelectedIndex).Value.ToString = "No" Then
        'Code to run if the selected list item in the radio button list has a value of "No"
    End If
```

Comment: Well that didn't work either BUT this is why: <asp:ListItem> No</asp:ListItem> its <space>No ...that is what I get for coding at 2:30am